# IE8 doesn't work for my JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, sharepoint-2010, javascript-objects

I have a big list in SharePoint 2010. Users needs to add and update items to get  unique item in a list. When I use "chrome" my js  runs very well , but when I use IE8 which is default Internet explorer, doesn't work. I got an error(Permission Denied when I debug). Please I need help. Thanks in advance

NB. We use IE11 but default is IE8. how can i add some scripts to work and compatible with IE8. Thanks Again

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some code to your question - no one has access to your `js`file. How should we know what you're trying to do?

Comment: <script>
 function PreSaveAction()
{
   lastname = $('input[title="testLN Required Field"]').val();
    firstname = $('input[title="testFN"]').val();
    emailaddress = $('input[title="testEmail"]').val();
</script>

Comment: Close the function at the end `<script> function PreSaveAction() { lastname = $('input[title="testLN Required Field"]').val(); firstname = $('input[title="testFN"]').val(); emailaddress = $('input[title="testEmail"]').val(); } </script>`

Comment: @Lul Put the code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Thanks Guys for prompt respond. eeetee answer my question . Thanks all

Comment: Then you might mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You might be using a newer version of jQuery.

If you need to support older browsers like Internet Explorer 6-8, Opera 12.1x or Safari 5.1+, use jQuery 1.12.

You can find it [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/#jquery-all-1.x)

Comment: Yes . We use IE8 which one compatible ? you mean jQuery Core 1.12.4?

Comment: Yes, the latest 1.12 should work. Also, do you have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` **under** your script tag? If so, make sure that meta tag is the first thing in your head.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciated . Its work now